# Is there a way I can validate multiple inputs through InputBox for integers?

Tags: arrays, validation, delphi, delphi-7

I am basically new to Delphi and I have been given an assignment where I have to sort an integer array, and also validate every input.

I have taken inputs of the array through the `InputBox()` function. The code for which goes like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for i := 0 to Length(arr)-1 do
  begin
    arr[i] := StrToInt(InputBox('Program to sort integers', 'Enter 5 integers', ''));
  end;
```

I have also tried putting a `try..except` block to catch errors, but it is not working as expected. The `try..except` block goes something like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for i := 0 to Length(arr)-1 do
  begin
    try
      arr[i] := StrToInt(InputBox('Program to sort integers', 'Enter 5 integers', ''));
    except
      ShowMessage('Invalid input');
    end;
```

The problem is that on clicking the button, the above `OnClick` event handler gets executed, but the `except` block doesn't.

What should I now do so that input gets validated?

If you want to know more things about my form components, then I’ve added one label, one ListBox to display a sorted array and one button (which you know by name as Button1.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which actual input do you enter and what do you expect from it? Also your code always misses `end;` to close loops.

Comment: Integer input strictly.

Comment: Hey Amigo, I hope you understood the qts.

Comment: In what situation do you expect the `except` branch to execute while it does not?

Comment: If you only enter `5`, `4096`, `65536` and such there will never be an exception. Enter `Text` or `3.5` or `µ³` to raise one.

Comment: Tom, okay. But now how would I validate it to accept only integer values, whereas it will show prompt saying "Invalid value" on entering any other value ?

Comment: Amigo, what do you mean by u3 ?

Comment: I am stuck in that place itself.

Comment: A few hours later, I realized that perhaps here's a misunderstanding what you actually are asking. So, when you originally asked *Is there a way I can validate .... through InputBox ....*, what exactly did you mean with *validation*? Between min and max, only positive or negative values or what. As the values already are in an integer array, I don't see what good the `InputBox` would or could do. Mentioned validations are though trivial to implement in code.

Comment: Between min and Max of Integers.

Comment: Normally you would create a form and have 5 TEditBox or similar on it, rather than popping inputboxes.

Comment: I fully agree with @RohitGupta

Comment: Hey @Tom, what I mean to say is that to validate integer input in an edit box you have this piece of code below, which we have to put under Edit1's OnKeyPress event. The code goes as follows                                                                                            procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  // #8 is Backspace
  if not (Key in [#8, '0'..'9']) then begin
    ShowMessage('Invalid key');
    // Discard the key
    Key := #0;
  end;
end;

Comment: So, what i want to ask is that, is there any way there in delphi 7 I can use to check whether each and every key user will input into input box is within limit or not i.e. it will show a dialog saying "Invalid input" if user tries to input anything other than integers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `OnKeyPress()` event as you show in your comment! But, if you want that the user can simply hit `Enter` to mark the end of a value, you also need to accept #13 as a valid key.

Thus, the first test in the `OnKeyPress` event becomes

```
if not (Key in [#8, #13, '0'..'9']) then
begin
  Key := #0;
  Exit;
end;
```

Then you need to handle the #13 key: (pseudocode)

```
if key = #13 then
begin
  // get the value of entered digits using `StrToInt()` function
  // to generalize, use `TEdit(Sender)` to refer to the current edit control
  // verify value against min and max values
  // if previous test succeeds, 
    // add to array
    // clear the edit control text
  // else show error msg
end
```

All other accepted keys are handled by the control.

Comment: But, is there anyway I can put restriction on edit box to accept only integers of certain range ?

Comment: No, not in Delphi 7 (as you have tagged your question). A property `NumbersOnly: boolean` was introduced in a later version, but that doesn't limit entered values to a certain range. So, in Delphi 7 you need to filter accepted keys and limit accepted values yourself in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't restrict InputBox but you can make your own InputBox with a simple form with Edit box and label and buttons.
To restrict edit box to accept only integers of certain range you have to options :

1. Make a new Edit class inherited from TEdit

```
      TIntegerEdit = class(TEdit)
      protected
        procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
        procedure KeyUp(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
        procedure KeyPress(var Key: Char); override;
        procedure DoEnter; override;
        procedure DoExit; override;
      end;
```

2)Use TEdit events to reach your goal. Look at the following sample.

Our form contains an edit control and two buttons. The Edit OnKeyUp & OnKeyDown use the same event.

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edt1: TEdit;
    BtnOk: TButton;
    BtnCancel: TButton;
    procedure Edt1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure Edt1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    procedure Edt1Enter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edt1Exit(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FOldText : string;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

Here is the code used to restrict the Edit to range 1000 to 5000.

```
    procedure TForm1.Edt1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    begin
      // if not in range '0' .. '9' , VK_BACK, VK_TAB, VK_RETURN
      if not ((Key in [48..57]) or (Key in [VK_BACK, VK_TAB, VK_RETURN])) then
        Key := 0;
    end;
    
    procedure TForm1.Edt1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    var
      i : Integer;
    begin
      if not ((Key in ['0'..'9']) or (Ord(Key) in [VK_BACK, VK_TAB, VK_RETURN])) then
        Key := #0;
    end;
    
    procedure TForm1.Edt1Enter(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      FOldText := '';
      Edt1Exit(Self);
      FOldText := Edt1.Text;
    end;
    
    procedure TForm1.Edt1Exit(Sender: TObject);
    const
      MinVal = 1000;
      MaxVal = 5000;
    var
      IntVal, E: Integer;
    begin
      Val(Edt1.Text, IntVal, E);
      if E  0 then //Do we have an error?
        Edt1.Text := FOldText;
    
      if (IntVal  MaxVal) then
        Edt1.Text := FOldText;
    end;
```